# Error JavaFX Eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Tengo un problema al usar `TableView` con Eclipse NEON el método `refresh` del type TableView, me da el siguiente error:

> The method refresh() from the type TableView is not visible

Alguien sabe ¿Cómo se puede solucionar? o ¿A qué se debe?

Gracias.

Comment: Yo no veo en la [api oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) que TableView tenga un método refresh. Supongo que es un método que has creado tú y lo has hecho private/protected.

Comment: No se si me equivocaré yo pero me parece que en J8u60 implementaron el tableView refresh().
    /**
     * Call this function to force the TableView to re-evaluate itself.***/
    private void refresh() {
        getProperties().put(TableViewSkinBase.REFRESH, Boolean.TRUE);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

En el eclipse NEON se me había puesto el jre1.8.0 he puesto el jre 1.8.0.111 y ya me funciona.

Muchas gracias.